# SQLAlchemy problems with inherited classes in the same table

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

Since alembic version 0.9 I have some serious problems on two systems. Both have Python 3.4.3 and Alembic 0.9.1 (via pip) installed. I also updated all the other python packages. The only difference is that the on is a Windows system and the other a Linux (Ubuntu).

On system A SQLAlchemy suddenly starts throwing the error `Table 'mytable' is already defined for this MetaData instance.  Specify 'extend_existing=True' to redefine options and columns on an existing Table object.`

The strange part is that this Model is used unchanged for several months.
But if SQLAlchemy wants the `extend_existing=True` entry - why not.

After adding the `extend_existing=True` entry to my model as shown at the end of this question everything worked fine on system A.
Now however SQLAlchemy complains on system B (which had no problem before). 
The error on system B is now 
`Can't place __table_args__ on an inherited class with no table.`.

Now I am locked in the strange situation that if I add the 'extend_existing=True' it works an system A but fails on system B and if I omit this setting it is just the other way around!

**What is wrong with SQLAlchemy and how to get a version that works on all systems?**

The following classes are defined in my model (just a small excerpt from a pretty large model file).

```
class Base(db.Model):
   __tablename__ = 'mytable'
    polymorphic_type = db.Column(db.String(20))
    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_on': polymorphic_type,
        'with_polymorphic': '*',
    }

class InheritedOne(Base):
    # the following line was added to make it work on system A
    __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}
    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'inheritedOne'
    }

class InheritedOneTwo(Base):
    # the following line was added to make it work on system A
    __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}
    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'inheritedTwo'
    }
```

Comment: What version of `flask-sqlalchemy` do you have on both systems?

Comment: You were right, the systems had different `flask-sqlalchemy` versions installed. System A had v2.2 and system B was running v2.1. Looks like this is an undocumented change of version 2.2 - at least there is nothing in the [changelog](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.2/changelog/).

Comment: I think it has something to do with the auto `__tablename__` logic. I'd suggest explicitly declaring `__tablename__` in inheritance scenarios because it can be confusing.

Comment: Because of other problems (foreign key relationships broken) I had to go back to flask-sqlalchemy 2.1. From my perspective v2.2 is just broken and I will stick with v2.1.